# AbstractHttpMessage getParams().setParameter construct depcrcated ~ How to modernize?

Tags: java, httprequest

I am working to modernize old legacy code, and while doing that ran into some deprecated constructs that I can't figure out how to handle. They all look somewhat like this:

```
        HttpPost oauthVerificationRequest = new HttpPost(authURL);
        oauthVerificationRequest.getParams().setParameter(OAUTH_TOKEN_KEY, oauthToken);
        HttpResponse oauthVerificationRequestResponse = client.getHttpClient().execute(oauthVerificationRequest);
```

There, my IDE complains that both `getParams()` as well as `setParameter` is deprecated.

The thing is, written as it is like this, I understand exactly what is happening. The deprecated line sets the value of the parameter with the key `OAUTH_TOKEN_KEY` of the request to the value of `oauthToken`, and probably creates it if it doesn't exist.

However, even knowing that this is what is supposed to happen in this line, I have been unable to find a way to write this line in a modern way. I've tried to figure it out, but the new way of constructing a AbstractHttpMessage simply confuses me.

Since I learn best by examples, could someone please provide me with a "translation" of the above code to the new logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, once again it seems that writing down my thoughts as a question helped get my mind down on the right track to find the solution. So to answer my own question, the correct way to write above statement in the new logic would be:

```
URIBuilder oauthVerificationRequestBuilder = new URIBuilder(authUrl);
oauthVerificationRequestBuilder.setParameter(OAUTH_TOKEN_KEY, oauthToken);
HttpPost oauthVerificationRequest = new HttpPost(oauthVerificationRequestBuilder.build());
HttpResponse oauthVerificationRequestResponse = client.getHttpClient().execute(oauthVerificationRequest);
```

So basically, you first create a builder, then set the parameters inside the builder, and then create the request using `builder.build()` as its parameter.

Bonus Question:

Is there also a way to get the `addHeader()` modification into the builder? Because right now, the entire construct looks like this for me, and it feels kinda inconsistent to use the builder for the parameters, and then slapping the header on top of the request the "old fashioned" way:

```
        URIBuilder oauthVerificationRequestBuilder = new URIBuilder(authUrl);
        oauthVerificationRequestBuilder.setParameter(OAUTH_TOKEN_KEY, oauthToken);
        oauthVerificationRequestBuilder.setParameter(OAUTH_VERIFIER_KEY, oauthVerifier);
        oauthVerificationRequestBuilder.setParameter(AUTHORIZE_KEY, VALUE_STRING_TRUE);
        HttpPost oauthVerificationRequest = new HttpPost(oauthVerificationRequestBuilder.build());
        oauthVerificationRequest.addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE_KEY, CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED_UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling "java httppost" gives [a link to the documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html). Looking for `getParams()` in the docs, shows that it is inherited from `AbstractHttpMessage` and another google search found [the docs for that class](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html#getParams()). That docs explains what to do instead of using the deprecated method:

> Deprecated. (4.3) use constructor parameters of configuration API provided by HttpClient

I hope this helps some future reader. Good libraries will document what the suggested replacement is for deprecated methods. It's always a good idea to consult the documentation for these suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I found that too during my initial search. Unfortunately, the phrase "use constructor parameters of configuration API provided by HttpClient" did not mean anything to me, so it took me a while to figure out my own solution. Even now I can't tell for sure whether the solution I came up with is the intended one. But It works. =^,^'=

Comment: @KiraResari I believe in the context of your code, you need to look at the constructor for `HttpPost`. Find the documentation and read about what parameters it accepts.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple by [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http API.

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequestBuilder.create(
  ClientBuilder.create().build();
)
.build();

Response response = httpRequest.target(authURL)
.addParameter(OAUTH_TOKEN_KEY, oauthToken)
.addParameter(ANOTHER_PARAM, "VALUE")
.addHeader(ANY_HEADER, "VALUE")
.post();
```

Dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jsunsoft.http</groupId>
  <artifactId>http-request</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```